# Specify PhantomJs download directory without CasperJs using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I'm working with PhamtomJs 2.0 and Protractor 2.1.0. 
My goal is to test file integrity (checksum) after download, for that I've searched a way to specify PhantomJs download directory and I found that the only way was with CasperJs. Is there way to do that without CasperJs directly with Protractor ?

Comment: also in need of this